# populate an array with different object type( and randomly assign a value to their parameters) using a loop?

Tags: java

Hi can someone please demonstrate how a I can fill and array of type reference with different Object type.

I've created the class(triangle,circle,rectangle) for the corresponding object but I cannot figure out a way to have each objects of thoses classes to fill each index of an array

I am new to java and I've been stuck on assignment.

**assignment question:**
Populate this array randomly with objects that can be of any
of the following types:Triangle,Circle,and Rectangle.The state of each object(e.g., position, or radius, etc.) is also randomly assign

Comment: If each of the your classes implemented a common interface e.g. `Shape`, then you could have an array of `Shape`

Comment: Is each shape a class? In other words do you have a `Triangle` class and a `Circle` class and a `Rectangle` class? If you do then do those classes have the same superclass? Maybe you also have a `Shape` class?

Comment: yes each shape have a class and I have a Shape class. but according to the requirement I turned the shape class to abstract class.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it in a few ways. First one is put your different objects into a collection of raw `Object` type. For this case you won't need to implement any interface but need to cast the object to your desired type while retrieving from the list. While this approach is simple and works a few time it is not recommended.

The other approach would be if you implement a common Shape interface to your all classes and then create a list of Shape. you can then put all your shapes in that collection. You can also invoke common methods of shape that you can  define on the interface while retrieved from the list. You can also make `Shape` an `Abstract` class or a Regular Class and use it as a `Super` class and extend your classes from `Shape`

```
public class Triangle implements Shape {
}

public class Circle implements Shape {
}

public class Rectangle implements Shape {
}

public interface Shape {
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    Triangle t = new Triangle();
    Circle c = new Circle();
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
    
    // Raw Type
    List<Object> shapeListRaw = new ArrayList<>();
    shapeListRaw.add(t);
    shapeListRaw.add(c);
    shapeListRaw.add(r);
    
    // Strictly Typed
    List<Shape> shapeListTyped = new ArrayList<>();
    shapeListTyped.add(t);
    shapeListTyped.add(c);
    shapeListTyped.add(r);

    //Similarly Raw type array
    Object[] shapeArrRaw = new Object[3];
    shapeArrRaw[0] = t;
    shapeArrRaw[1] = c;
    shapeArrRaw[2] = r;

    //Typed Array
    Shape[] shapeArrTyped = new Shape[3];
    shapeArrTyped[0] = t;
    shapeArrTyped[1] = c;
    shapeArrTyped[2] = r;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a factory pattern.
Visit https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

```java
public class ShapeFactory {
    //use getShape method to get object of type shape 
    public Shape getShape(String shapeType){
        if(shapeType == null){
            return null;
        }
        if(shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("CIRCLE")){
            Circle c = new Circle();
            c.setRadius(Math.random()*100);
            return c;
         
        } else if(shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("RECTANGLE")){
            return new Rectangle();
         
        } else if(shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("SQUARE")){
            return new Square();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class Main{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<Shape> shape=new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is more inclined to design pattern, design. Even though this approach indicates an indirect way to solve the problem mentioned in the question it would be helpful if your proposed solution is more precise and complete.